# do addition in while loop's same row value

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I fetch some value form database and displayed using while loop. Below is my code for while loop.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
                echo"<tr>";             
                $query2 = "select product_quantity from `order` where product_id = $row[product_id]";
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){                     
                    $qauntity = $row2['product_quantity'];
                    echo $qauntity;
                }
   }
```

From the above code I am getting this output: 
     1
     24

Now I want to do addition of that 2 and 4 that is 2+4=6.
Kindly help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would probably be far easier and quicker if you did a JOIN in your first query (that you do not show in the code fragment), rather than performing multiple selects within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just the addition, not the original numbers, you can edit your SQL query so you get the sum of selected numbers:

```
$query2 = "select SUM(product_quantity) from `order` where product_id = $row[product_id]";
```

After this, you don't need the second while loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like pretty easy thing to do. Just add a counter and increment it by quantity inside your inner while loop, correct me if that is not what you desire.

Here's how inner loop should look :

```
$total = 0;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){                     
    $qauntity = $row2['product_quantity'];
    $total += $qauntity;
}
echo $total;
```